# NUCLEO-GO71RB with one-wire AT21CS11 EEPROM

Tags: eeprom, 1-wire

I am trying to interface an AT21CS11 EEPROM  with a SMT32 micro on a Nucleo board. I have adapted the code of the certified demo https://github.com/MicrochipTech/SWI-Connector-Demo.git to the SMT32 to my hardware, but I am not able to even read the slave address.

The pin I use to read from is set as open drain pull-up, moreover I have implemented a microseconds delay function as described in https://controllerstech.com/create-1-microsecond-delay-stm32/.

I hope someone can give me some tips according to your experience.

The code of my main.c:

```c
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2021 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
  *
  * This software component is licensed by ST under BSD 3-Clause license,
  * the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with the
  * License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
  *                        opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "spi.h"
#include "tim.h"
#include "usart.h"
#include "gpio.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include "stdio.h"
#include "operations.h"
#include "low_level.h"
#include <stdint.h>

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */
/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
 uint8_t comunicationSpeed=0;
 uint8_t slaveAddress=0x00;
 uint16_t count = 0x0000;                                //global variable for connector count
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
/*void ADS1118_init(union Config * configRegister);
float ADS1118_RW32bit(union Config * configRegister,GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx, uint16_t GPIO_Pin);
double ADS1118_getTemp(union Config * configRegister,GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx, uint16_t GPIO_Pin);
void ADS1118_RW32bit_int(union Config * configRegister,GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx, uint16_t GPIO_Pin, uint8_t *bufferRX);*/

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  MX_TIM1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim1);
  //HAL_SYSCFG_StrobeDBattpinsConfig(SYSCFG_UCPD1_STROBE); //??


  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
     // HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, EEPROM_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
     // HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, EEPROM_Pin);

     if(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(Button_GPIO_Port,Button_Pin)==0){
     slaveAddress= scanDeviceAddress();
     HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2,)
     printf(slaveAddress);
      }

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIDiv = RCC_HSI_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = RCC_PLLM_DIV4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 80;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = RCC_PLLQ_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = RCC_PLLR_DIV5;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */



/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

This is the gpio.c file, the electrical circuit has a 1.8k ohm pull-up resistor in parallel with a 0.1nF capacitor.

```c
#include "gpio.h" 
void MX_GPIO_Init(void) {
 GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
 /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */ 
__HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE(); 
__HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE(); 
__HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE(); 
__HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
 /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
 HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, EEPROM_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET); 
/*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
 HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, CS1_Pin|CS0_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
 /*Configure GPIO pin : PtPin */
 GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = Button_Pin;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT; 
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
 HAL_GPIO_Init(Button_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

 /*Configure GPIO pin : PtPin */ 
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = EEPROM_Pin;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_OD; 
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP; 
GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW; HAL_GPIO_Init(EEPROM_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct); }
```

Comment: Half of the code is missing. So is details of how the hardware is connected. Please add the details.

Comment: But you can't just drop a wall of (unformatted) code here, you need to make some attempt to narrow down the problem or at least limit the code the relevant parts.

Comment: i posted the gpio.c file, it was formatted, the posting has modified it

Comment: You use three ` symbols on one line at the start of a code block, and three of them on one line at the end of the code block.

Comment: @Simona: You should edit your additional information into the question instead of adding it as an answer.  Move the stuff from your "answer" to the end of your question, then delete the answer.

Comment: @Simona - Hi, I see you are getting help on how to use Stack Exchange (SE) from other site members.  SE rules differ from typical "linear" forums. Please see the [tour] & [help] now, to get an overview of the main site rules. Don't use the box at the bottom of the screen labeled "Your Answer" unless you are providing the full and final answer to your question (which is different from any other answers) and you are ready to close the topic. Any new info / clarification etc,. should be an edit to the question. Please [edit] the question to explain your troubleshooting actions & results so far.